# Expected a string or 'Doc' as input, but got: <class 'list'>.when cleaning text on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have a pandas dataframe with survey responses.  Sometimes those responses are very long text with many sentences.  So I want to:

1. Split responses in sentences
2. Clean Text

For Number 1 I did the following:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
q1["cleantext"] = q1["Line"].apply(lambda x: [sent.text for sent in nlp(x).sents])
q1 = q1.explode("cleantext", ignore_index=True)
```

For number 2, I tried this: https://www.kaggle.com/code/balatmak/text-preprocessing-steps-and-universal-pipeline/notebook

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

import string
import spacy 
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator


nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

class TextPreprocessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,
                 nlp = nlp,
                 n_jobs=1):
        """
        Text preprocessing transformer includes steps:
            1. Punctuation removal
            2. Stop words removal
            3. Lemmatization

        nlp  - spacy model
        n_jobs - parallel jobs to run
        """
        self.nlp = nlp
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, *_):
        X_copy = X.copy()

        partitions = 1
        cores = mp.cpu_count()
        if self.n_jobs <= -1:
            partitions = cores
        elif self.n_jobs <= 0:
            return X_copy.apply(self._preprocess_text)
        else:
            partitions = min(self.n_jobs, cores)

        data_split = np.array_split(X_copy, partitions)
        pool = mp.Pool(cores)
        data = pd.concat(pool.map(self._preprocess_part, data_split))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return data

    def _preprocess_part(self, part):
        return part.apply(self._preprocess_text)

    def _preprocess_text(self, text):
        doc = self.nlp(text)
        removed_punct = self._remove_punct(doc)
        removed_stop_words = self._remove_stop_words(removed_punct)
        return self._lemmatize(removed_stop_words)

    def _remove_punct(self, doc):
        return (t for t in doc if t.text not in string.punctuation)

    def _remove_stop_words(self, doc):
        return (t for t in doc if not t.is_stop)

    def _lemmatize(self, doc):
        return ' '.join(t.lemma_ for t in doc)
```

and

```
text = TextPreprocessor(n_jobs=-1).transform(q1['Line'])
```

However I get this error.

```
[E866] Expected a string or 'Doc' as input, but got: <class 'list'>.
```

I could do it the other way around, but then when cleaning you lose all punctuations, etc, so the sentence tokenizer wouldnt work correctly I guess

What am I missing here?

full error:

```
Output menu
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_12272/2510622359.py", line 51, in _preprocess_part
    return part.apply(self._preprocess_text)
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4433, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1082, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1137, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_12272/2510622359.py", line 54, in _preprocess_text
    doc = self.nlp(text)
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1005, in __call__
    doc = self._ensure_doc(text)
  File "/anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1096, in _ensure_doc
    raise ValueError(Errors.E866.format(type=type(doc_like)))
ValueError: [E866] Expected a string or 'Doc' as input, but got: <class 'list'>.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 text = TextPreprocessor(n_jobs=-1).transform(q1['cleantext2'])

Input In [23], in TextPreprocessor.transform(self, X, *_)
     42 data_split = np.array_split(X_copy, partitions)
     43 pool = mp.Pool(cores)
---> 44 data = pd.concat(pool.map(self._preprocess_part, data_split))
     45 pool.close()
     46 pool.join()

File /anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:364, in Pool.map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    359 def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
    360     '''
    361     Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
    362     in a list that is returned.
    363     '''
--> 364     return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

File /anaconda/envs/GPSAnalysis/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:771, in ApplyResult.get(self, timeout)
    769     return self._value
    770 else:
--> 771     raise self._value

ValueError: [E866] Expected a string or 'Doc' as input, but got: <class 'list'>.
```

Comment: Hi! COuld you please include the full error trace?

Comment: You shouldn't do that kind of preprocessing before passing text to spaCy. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10243

Comment: @polm23 very helpful reading